# Connecting an Access form to a SQL Server

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been working on a project that is near completion but this final part is causing me some headaches because I have never done this before and I am having a hard time finding the research to help get me going I have no idea where to even begin. The project is as follows: (this is the context of the email from my boss)

You will need to look up how to check for connectivity using vba. The server you will connect to is the HRLearnDev. I have an access form I will send you that has the connection info in macros on it, where I did something similar. The difference is, my program connected directly to the server. Yours will need to write to a local table, do a check for connectivity when the access file is opened, or every few minutes or something, and if the check reads that there is a connection, write the data from the local server table to the remote server table, then truncate the local table.

I am really stuck and I am running out of options so any insight on where to start to look that is for beginners would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what your actual question here is... What is your specific problem?

Comment: I have no idea where to begin, this is all the instruction I have been given

Comment: begin by writing out what is needed. Specific points - ie. Excel spreadsheet ( what does it do, whats the purpose? ), VBA Project - what is it supposed to do? Connect to DB and retrieve data to a speadsheet? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to check the connection:

```
Public Sub TestConnection()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim canConnect As Boolean

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection   
cnn.Provider = "sqloledb"
cnn.Open "Data Source=HRLearnDev;Initial Catalog=YourTableName;UserID=userID;Password='password';"   
If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
    canConnect = True
    cnn.Close
End If   
MsgBox "Can you connect? - " & canConnect

End Sub
```

Honestly, this is obviously a homework problem and I don't think giving you the entire answer would be the right thing to do, but that should get you started.

Comment: The alternative was to close it because A) it's too general, and B) it includes no attempted code and doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the technology.  Instead, I gave the OP enough to start with.